# Efficient way to create daily summary table

Tags: window-functions, redshift

I'm trying to create a daily summary table that captures characteristics of each client known as of every given date that my company has been in business. The challenge is that there are so many clients that if I try to create a row for every client-date pair my table becomes too big to process.

Fortunately each client does not change daily, so I keep a compact table of all the unique client-date pairs (see `sparse_daily_transactions_states` in "query 1") and then use window functions (see `dense_daily_transactions` in "query 1") to fill in the blanks when I need to query the daily summary table for particular date ranges. Querying all dates for all clients still results in an exploding data size problem.

I was hoping to create a view to hide this messy logic (see "query 1"). The idea is that a user could specify a date range in the where cause of the view (see "query 2"), and then the view would only run for the user specified dates without touching all of the data, but that doesn't seem possible based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401749/pass-in-where-parameters-to-postgresql-view).

I'd like to hide complexity from my users as much as possible. Is there a way to create something that 1) looks and behaves like a table (I don't want to have to explain functions to my users), and 2) doesn't blow up my dataset? I'm doing this on Redshift, by the way.

**Edit 1:**

My question has been flagged as too broad, so I'm adding code to narrow the scope.

Below is the huge dump of code that I to want hide from users. Even if I didn't hide the code, running it for all dates and all clients is far too much for my cluster to handle by putting it behind a materialized view or generating the entire view each time at run-time.

**Query 1:** What I want to capture with a view

```
 UPDATE public.client_daily_summary
    SET ar_balance = dense.ar_balance
   FROM (
   WITH client_dates AS
(SELECT clients.clientkey,
        dw_date.the_date::DATE AS the_date
   FROM dw_date
   JOIN public.clients AS clients
        ON TRUE),

        daily_transaction_events AS
(SELECT client_dates.clientkey,
        client_dates.the_date,
        SUM(transactions.aramt) AS aramt
   FROM client_dates
   LEFT JOIN raw_fsprod.transactions AS transactions
        ON client_dates.clientkey = transactions.clientkey
           AND client_dates.the_date::DATE = transactions.postdate::DATE
           AND transactions.STATUS='0'
  GROUP BY client_dates.clientkey,
        client_dates.the_date),

        sparse_daily_transactions_states AS
(SELECT events.clientkey,
        events.the_date,
        SUM(events.aramt)
            OVER(PARTITION BY clientkey
            ORDER BY the_date ASC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ar_balance
   FROM daily_transaction_events AS events),

        dense_daily_transactions AS
(SELECT sparse.clientkey,
        sparse.the_date,
        LAST_VALUE (ar_balance IGNORE NULLS)
            -- must use PARTITION and ORDER BY values that are never NULL
            OVER (PARTITION BY sparse.clientkey
            ORDER BY sparse.the_date ASC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                 AND CURRENT ROW) AS ar_balance
   FROM sparse_daily_transactions_states AS sparse)

 SELECT clientkey,
        the_date,
        ar_balance
   FROM dense_daily_transactions) AS dense
  WHERE client_daily_summary.clientkey = dense.clientkey
        AND client_daily_summary.the_date::DATE = dense.the_date::date;
```

My users shouldn't have to think about all of that complicated logic. They should only have to use the code below.

**Query 2:** Example of what I want my users to be able to do:

```
SELECT invoices.invoicekey,
       invoices.days_open,
       invoices.balance,
       clients.ar_balance
  FROM public.invoice_daily_summary AS invoices
  LEFT JOIN public.client_daily_summary AS clients
       ON invoices.clientkey = clients.clientkey
          AND invoice.snapshot_date = clients.snapshot_date
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM clients.snapshot_date) IN (2014,2015)
```

The code the user enters in the `WHERE` clause should enable the view to only pull the data that is necessary so that I avoid the exploding data problem.

Comment: A view is something that looks and behaves like a table.

Comment: @mustaccio I've added code to my question (which now makes it substantially longer, which is why I didn't include it originally) to narrow the scope. Let me know if those changes are sufficient.

Comment: Unless things are different with redshift from most SQL implementations, all views can be `SELECT`ed from, but only some (or, possible, no) views can be `UPDATE`d. Will your users be running updates/inserts, or only selects?

Comment: My users will only select from the view not update or insert into it